# Recursion of a Linked List: Recurrence Relations and Recursive Trees

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, big-o, recurrence

I had to write a recursive relation that counted the number of nodes in a singly linked list. I have done so and the code is available below. Following the coding of the program, I am to provide the recurrence relation of the program a recursive tree method of the program. For he recurrence relation I received was T(n) = T(n-1) + O(1), which I believe is right. I am confused on how to structure a recurrence tree for this and am wondering if I could get some help. Thank you.

Code:

```
int Length(struct Node* head) //must start at the head of the LL
{
if (head == NULL) //base case for the recursion
{ 
    return 0;
}
return 1 + Length(head->next);
}
```

Comment: It isn't really a "tree" as such if you only have one recursion path.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog that's what I was thinking and I believe that's where my confusion came from. With my understanding it would be a tree if T(n/b) where b > 1, because there is no division otherwise

Comment: If you really wanted draw a "tree" diagram, it would just look like a sloped straight line, since there is no branching. Doing so would give no additional insights.

Comment: Okay, that's how I envisioned it. It was a question asked to me and I was stumped on why that would even be a question asked. @meowgoesthedog